# push the contain of an array downwards

Tags: java

If I have an array of size 4 like this : `int[] array = new int[4];`
and I have

```
TextField text1 = new TextField();
TextField text2 = new TextField();
TextField text3 = new TextField();
TextField text4 = new TextField();
```

there text1 shows the contain of `array [0]`
text2 shows the contain of `array [1]`
text3 shows the contain of `array [2]`
text4 shows the contain of `array [3]`

If I want to push the contain of `array [0]` to `array [1]` and show that in my textfields, How do I do that?
thanks

Comment: text2.setText(Integer.toString(array[1]));

Comment: Replace index[1] with array[1] please. It was just to give you an idea.

Answer (score 1):

Simple:

```
index[2] = index[1];
index[1] = index[0];
```

you can use a for loop and it's counter if there are a lot of number of indices in the array.

After that, `textField.setText(index[wantedIndex]);`

Comment: @AllaAls: by that myTextField.setText(...); How else would you set the value of a textfield?

Comment: did you mean array[2] = array[1];

Comment: No. That is how you swap the elements in your array. In order to set that value in your textfield,you'll need to call it's setText(String text); method

Answer (score 1):

For the one cell only:

```
array[1] = array[0];
text2.setText(String.valueOf(array[1]));
```

If you want to push all elements in your array up by one:

```
TextField[] fields = {text1, text2, text3, text4};
for (int i = 3; i > 0; i--) {
    array[i] = array[i-1];
    fields[i].setText(String.valueOf(array[i]));
}
// previous content of array[3] is lost
// do sth with array[0] which remains unchanged
```

It is important to loop backwards through your array. Otherwise you you would override the cells before copying and fill all cells with the previous content of array[0].

BTW, it seems that you want to push upwards - not downwards, as indicated above.

Answer (score 0):

What you needs is basically two things

1. Swap the variables
2. Change the value of the TextField

To swap variables, you do the following:

```
array[2] = array[1]; //this overwrites value of array[2] with value of array[1]
```

To set the value of TextField, you need to invoke the `setText(String)` method and pass it a String. Since the value you want to set to the `TextField` is int hence, you need to first change it to String and then set it as follow:

```
//assuming that you have updated the value of array[2] to array[1]
text1.setText(String.valueOf(array[2]));
```

Above converts the integer in `array[2]` to `String` and then sets the `TextField`.

See the TextField documentation [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/TextField.html#setText(java.lang.String)). The method signature for setText() is as follow:

> public void setText(String t)
>
> Sets the text that is presented by this
>
> text component to be the specified text.